# How to change auto-generated code when creating new class in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Whenever I create a new Java file in Eclipse and check off the option to add `public static void main(String args[])`, this code is generated:

```
public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

How do i:

- Remove the `@param args` comment
- Change the indentation so each { is on a line of its own
- Remove the TODO auto generated comment

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The indention is a formatting issue while the comments is a template issue.

The templates are in **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates**. Browse all of them and look for the things you would like to change.

The Formatter is a little bit more complicated. You find it under **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter**. There are tons of options there but I'll just answer your question.

- Templates -> Comments -> Methods -> Edit and delete everything
- Formatter -> Edit -> Braces Tab -> Change which situations you want
- Templates -> Code -> Method Body -> Edit and delete everything

Answer (score 6):

1. In Eclipse Go to Window->Preferences
2. In Left Panel, Select Java->Code Style->Code Template
3. Under "Configure generated code and comments", Expand Comments-> select Methods,Click Edit
   Remove or replace the pattern ( * @param args),Click OK
4. Under "Configure generated code and comments", Expand Code-> select Method Body,Click Edit
   Remove or replace the pattern ( // TODO Auto-generated...),Click OK
5. Click OK !

Answer (score 1):

To configure it go to the :
window->preferences->java->code style->code templates

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse has a **lot** of configuration options. Take a look in the Windows | Preferences dialog (or the Eclipse Preferences pan on OSX).

If you dig deep enough - you'll find the options under Java | Code Style.

Comment: Already looked there but its the identation for brackets i'm having trouble with

Answer (score -1):

Also make sure you check "Use code formatter" in Java > Editor > Templates