# How do I decipher what this code does based on the comments and naming?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm exploring a large Java library, and came across this code. I'm wondering what the @Override is for, along with the # symbol in the comments.

Is this an incomplete function? It looks like that since it returns false always.

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see cascadas.supervision.components.SensorDataReady#evaluate(cascadas.ace.event.Event, cascadas.ace.session.Contract, cascadas.ace.session.Session, cascadas.ace.session.Session)
 */
@Override
public boolean evaluate(Event inputMessage, Contract contract,
        Session executionSession, Session globalSession) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

I appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what the pound (`#`) means, see [the documentation for the `@see` Javadoc tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#see). It basically designates a `package.class#member`.

The `(non-Javadoc)` part designates that this method will inherit its Javadoc from the Javadoc of one of its superclasses. The method comment is basically directing you to `SensorDataReady#evaluate` for this method's Javadoc.

`@Override` is an annotation. See its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html).

As for the method itself, it looks like [Eclipse-generated code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501648/how-to-change-auto-generated-code-when-creating-new-class-in-eclipse). Eclipse puts the `TODO` comment there to remind a developer to implement the overridden method.

Comment: Thank You So Much creemama(nice name : )

Answer (score 2):

`@Override` indicates the method is overriding a base class method.

Comment: Oh I see, so that method is in the class that it extends from, Thank You Very Much!

Comment: Well, the method is really there, it will indeed return false if called. However, if you removed `evaluate` from this class, any instance in code where `evaluate` was called would now revert to the parent class implementation.