# How to add default string in class in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any method I can configure eclipse to create class with default string as a first line

```
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Whenever I create a new java file in eclipse

Comment: Take a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501648/how-to-change-auto-generated-code-when-creating-new-class-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with  an adapted new Class template.

You can find it in the Preferences under **Java->Code Style->Code Templates** then switch to the right side of the dialog and select **Code->New Java files**

Answer (score 4):

Properties -> Java Code Style -> Code Templates.

Comment: dang! beat me by 48 seconds :)